# Set QGIS magnifier value lower than 10%

Tags: qgis

Since version 2.16, QGIS [contains a magnifier tool](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog216/index.html#feature-map-canvas-magnifier).

The tool itself is great, but I would like to set the magnifier to as low as 1%. However, QGIS enforces a minimum value of 10%, I cannot set lower values through the UI.

**Is the lower limit configurable somewhere, or can it be turned off?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want the magnifier to be at 1%? =)

Comment: @Joseph I'm trying to quality-check a large mbtiles file with different zoom levels, and I need some mechanism to prevent QGIS from using a lower-detail zoom level. In fact, the feature in QGIS that I'm missing is a "lock zoom level" for the mbtiles layer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do this from the GUI as the [source code for this minimum](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgsstatusbarmagnifierwidget.cpp#L30) is set to 10%.

But with a little help from python, we can change this from the **Python Console** by typing in:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().setValue("/Qgis/magnifier_factor_min", "0.01")
```

Restart QGIS and you should now be able to reduce the maginifier level to 1%.

---

Example:

- Magnifier at 100%

  [image: 100% image]

---

- Magnifier at 1% (***Warning: squinting may be required and could cause discomfort.***)

  [image: 1%]

Comment: I just realized that this only works partially for my case: I'm trying to see a detailed zoom level of a multi-zoom-level raster layer from "far away", without QGIS zooming out. But using the magnifier still switches to a higher zoom level, although not as aggressive as without the magnifier. Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: @theDmi - Hmm could be although I haven't really fully used or tested the magnifier tool yet. You could always submit a [bug report](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) to get confirmation.